# Add "New Folder" button to datasource picker in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I'd like to enable content editors to better structure their local datasources in the Sitecore Editor when using the experience editor to select datasources for renderings.

I'd like them to be able to create a new folder underneath which ever item they have selected in the tree that is show in the dialogue.

This might work by right click and pressing "add new folder", or a new button in the left hand pane which says "Add folder under selected item".

Could anyone point me in the right direction to how I might achieve this? Image attached for better context.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a module, there is a *Datasource Location* field in the *Editor Options* section allowing to specify one or more content locations from where content editors can select content for the rendering. More locations can be specified using a piped *query: syntax*, for example

[image: Datasource Location field management]